# SearchView and NavigationDrawer Android

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, searchview

I'm trying to implement in my application, which is characterized by the navigation drawer, I would like to implement the search view. Unfortunately, I get a null value nell'oncreatemenu etc ...

I do not understand where I am attaching a wrong image, the log cat and source code.
Thank you in advance, sincerely the same code but with no navigation drawer tabs dell'actionbar worked great. I do not understand, I tried searching on the internet but nothing ...
Source code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_action, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    //searchView.setQueryHint("Inserisci qualcosa da cercare");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

LogCat:

> 11-12 12:09:30.900  21373-21373/com.lillonet.megadownloaderpro E/﹕ Device driver API match
>       Device driver API version: 23
>       User space API version: 23
>   11-12 12:09:30.900  21373-21373/com.lillonet.megadownloaderpro E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013
>   11-12 12:10:01.740  21373-21373/com.lillonet.megadownloaderpro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.lillonet.megadownloaderpro.NavActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(NavActivity.java:344)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2578)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1056)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1259)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:80)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:119)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

[image]

XML CODE:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="Cerca"
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: Your `searchView` object is null. Without any XML this would be hard to solve.

Comment: Could you please confirm what you wanna achieve?
You're talking about navigation drawer, but you're showing code inside the onCreateOptionsMenu(), which is for the ActionBar.

Comment: XML was inflated in menu... his name is R.menu.main_action... see the image. @PedroOliveira

Comment: @PedroOliveira added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.widget.SearchView` should be `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` instead and use `app` prefix too. Also you should use `collapseActionView` on `app:showAsAction

Like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
android:title="Cerca"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: It's wrong the package is: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView, but it doesn't work also then included that

Comment: You're right. Also change your `showAsAction` to `collapseActionView` instead of `ifRoom`

Comment: I tryed but it doesn't work... :( this is the code: `<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Cerca"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />`

Comment: Use `app:actionViewClass` instead of `android:actionViewClass`